# Automatically scroll down page

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, vertical-scrolling

I am trying to get a specific div on my page to automatically start scrolling down, then back up once the page loads.

I have this written for my javascript:

```
<script> function scroll(speed) {
$('#scrollingcontent').animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() - $(window).height() }, speed, function() {
    $(this).animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, speed);
});
}

speed = 1000;

scroll(speed)
setInterval(function(){scroll(speed)}, speed * 2);</script>
```

Chrome is telling me that I have a reference error, and that $ is not defined. 
My div that i want animated has the id of scrollingcontent.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you have attached jQuery properly or not.

```
<head>
<script src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

More : - http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_install.asp

Hope this helps. Cheers!

Comment: I was missing that line, but it still isn't scrolling when I refresh the page.

Comment: Do you actually have div called (id) as ' scrollingcontent' ? If you inspect what does the browser says? Any error?

Comment: Yes, the div that needs to scroll is here: <div id="scrollingcontent">